# Orchard CMS - 2 identical Pagers in the summary list

Tags: pagination, orchardcms, pager

Is it possible to put the same pager at the top and bottom (before and after content) of a summary list within Orchard? I've spent a while trying to do this with the placement file but with no success.

My only other alternative is to do something like jQuery clone..??

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this technique: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/02/13/easy-content-templates-for-orchard-take-2.aspx, define your own zones that you target with placement, and then call display on the pagination zone twice.